# Compound Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to get a list of all Foreign Keys in a database. This list must include the reference table and column, the referenced table and column, the constraint name, and (for compound keys )the position of the referenced column within the compound foreign key.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way (includes ordinal position of fields):

```
select
    fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , fk.TABLE_NAME FK_Table
    , kcu.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column
    , ptc.TABLE_NAME PK_Table
    , ptKcu.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column
    , kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION
from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS fk
     on rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk
     on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
     on rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ptc
     on pk.TABLE_NAME = ptc.TABLE_NAME 
     and ptc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ptKcu
     on ptc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ptKcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        and kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION = ptKcu.ORDINAL_POSITION
--where
--  FK.TABLE_NAME = '<name of table containing foreign key>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this(From [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/11/27/viewing-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/)):-

```
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName, 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName, 
   COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName 
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
   ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

Also check out **[this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/)**